# Get rid of product-rec tag

Tags: support, retag-request

[product-rec](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/product-rec) looks to be a good candidate for deletion, or do we keep it around as a match for [software-rec](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/software-rec) and [hardware-rec](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/hardware-rec)?

Comment: I don't necessarily agree: Products can also be hardware. Better to have this tag removed entirely – seems like a good indicator for questions that might need to be closed.

Comment: @slhck: True, edited question accordingly. We already have specific tags for both software and hardware rec so I agree with you that we can get rid of this one.